RPi4 procedure for booting secondary CPUs
From https://github.com/s-matyukevich/raspberry-pi-os/blob/master/docs/lesson01/rpi-os.md I found such a statement:
The Raspberry Pi 3 has four core processors, and after the device is powered on, each core begins to
execute the same code.

This means that once control is taken over the kernel, all 4 cores starts executing it as they all would be primary CPUs, is this correct?
I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031690/booting-arm-cortex-a-secondary-cores-with-linux, but I have no idea what kind of boot_reg they're talking about
Is there any documentation which documents booting procedure for primary/secondary CPUs for ARMv8 (aarch64) overall and especially for RPi4 (BCM2711)? Thank you in advance!
